# Width of a page that contains mostly text

Tags: text, typography, blog

I'm working on a design for a blog. The blog is very text oriented. It contains long articles of thousands of words.

When I look around the web I see that blogs often have a 'fixed width' page size (when using Blogspot or Wordpress for example). But when I look at Wikipedia which is also very text heavy, it's responsive and the text is spanned at almost the monitor width.

So what would be a good approach for a heavy text based blog which will be mostly read on desktops? Go full width (responsive) or limit the width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Emil Ruder's book “Typographie”, as readers read a line of text, their attention wanes until they reach a new line, wherein they become refocused. At the corollary, when lines are too short, users deal with increased cognitive load as they refocus for each line.

As such, the general rule for readability is 50-75 characters per line, which can be achieved through limiting the max width.